# PHP чем одна строка отличается от другой?

Tags: php

Есть переменная из wordpress (`$wordpess_string`), в ней есть строка.

Есть моя переменная (`$a`).

```php
$a = '432.00 VAT';
var_dump($a); // string(10) "432.00 VAT"

var_dump($wordpess_string); // string(134) "432.00 VAT"

$compare = $a == $wordpess_string;
var_dump($compare); // bool(false)

strcmp($a, $wordpess_string); // int(-8)
```

В чем разница между ними и почему их сравнение приводит к отрицательному результату?

- string(10) "432.00 VAT"
- string(134) "432.00 VAT"

И что значит 10 и 134 после string?

Comment: значит в переменной wordpess_string больше чем то, что указано........... потому что если скопировать это значение сейчас и куда-то вставить то там будет также 10 символов

Comment: *"И что значит 10 и 134 после string?"* --- длина строки.

Comment: Покажите результат `base64_encode($wordpress_string)`, тогда можно будет сказать что там за лишние символы.

Comment: PHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9Indvb2NvbW1lcmNlLVByaWNlLWFtb3VudCBhbW91bnQiPjxiZGk+NDMyLDAwJm5ic3A7PHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9Indvb2NvbW1lcmNlLVByaWNlLWN1cnJlbmN5U3ltYm9sIj48L3NwYW4+PC9iGFGu=PC9cZGk=PCWQz==

Comment: Html, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Что-то вы криво скопировали. Тут многовато знаков `=`. В любом случае, у вас там явно не строка `432.00 VAT`, а какой-то кусок HTML `<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>432,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"></span>...`